# vector addition - resultant of two vectors

Tags: vectors

Suppose two ships are moving in different directions at some angle between them and we have to find the distance between them we use the formula$R^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta$ 
But if we have to find the resultant between two forces we use the formula$R^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\theta$. Why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you're the observer at the point $O$, one ship is at the point $A$ and the other is at the point $B$:

[image: Ships]

The vector that joins you to the ship $A$ is $\vec{a}$, and the vector that joins you to the ship $B$ is $\vec{b}$, and the vector that joins ship $A$ to ship $B$ is $\vec{c}$. So we have:

- $O \rightarrow A = \vec{a}$
- $O \rightarrow B = \vec{b}$

The challenge is to calculate the vector $\vec{c}$ because that represents the displacement between the two ships. To get from $A$ to $B$ we can go from $A$ to $O$ then from $O$ to $B$:

- $A \rightarrow O = -\vec{a}$
- $O \rightarrow B = \vec{b}$

Note that the vector that joins $A$ to $O$ is $-\vec{a}$ because it's the reverse of the vector joining $O$ to $A$. The vector $\vec{c}$ is calculated by adding our two vectors so:

$$ \vec{c} = -\vec{a} + \vec{b} $$

This is different from the vector we get if we add $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$:

[image: Add vectors]

And that's why you have two different equations. It's because you are calculating the lengths of two different vectors.

Answer (score 0):

To find the distance between things, you subtract.
To get the result of adding vectors, you - well - add, obviously.

Adding and subtracting are, well, different. I'm reminded of that question involving change:

Three people pay ¤10 to share the cost of a ¤27 item. The server only has ¤5s, so they leave the two dollars as a tip. So each person paid ¤9, and the server got ¤2 - that's ¤29. Where did the other dollar go?

You have to add and subtract the right things.